# python 3 open window on screen 2 by default (multi displays)

Tags: python-3.x, window, tkinter, multiple-monitors

I have a program that opens two separate windows, one of which is full screen. I would like to open the full screen window on the secondary display (this program will require at least 2 screens to be properly functional, but is not enforced) and the other window on the main display.

Is there any way to do this in python 3 and tkinter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not a very portable solution, but what I have seen done in the past is to use absolute positioning (using wxPython, though).  So if you have two monitors set at 1024X768 in a side by side setup, the first screen's x would be 0, and the second screen's x would be 1024 (or 768 if I have my x's and y's mixed up ;).

Comment: This may be a possible solution, although not the prettiest. I will look further into it. Thanks.
The way I remember my x's and y's is in two parts firstly the sentence "X is a cross". A cross is across when you remove the space. get it?
Secondly, a screen's width is generally wider than it is tall so the bigger value will be x.